# Pulling data from private API using xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest

I need a little help trying to pull data from a private api. Here is my code

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.open("GET", "https://pubgtracker.com/api/profile/pc/silentsushix3?api=bc98fb9b-31be-4df4-ac36-fff4c5230b04", true);
xhr.send();

console.log(xhr.status);
console.log(xhr.response);
```

when this part of the script gets ran, it returns a 200 status but an undefined response.

I can not, for the life of me, figure out how to pull out any specific data, or any data at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are not listening to the event of xhr

Comment: The XMLHttpRequest runs asynchronously and will not have a result yet because you check for it immediately. See this for background on the concept https://pubgtracker.com/api/profile/pc/silentsushix3?api=bc98fb9b-31be-4df4-ac36-fff4c5230b04

Comment: @Andreas indeed! https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript

Answer (score 0):

This might help...

```
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState < 4)
                console.log("Loading...");
            else if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.status < 300)
                {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                } 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe add some more explanation on what about this is different and what the OP's core mistake was?

Comment: Awesome Ali, that,worked perfectly. After I was able to parse the infor and pull out the selected info! Thanks guys. I will post the rest of my code for those who need it in future.